# the render tag is not working for styling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, render

was using the

```
<%= render partial: "/shared/navigation" %>
```

to clear up my application.html.erb. I created the new folder and file but i get a not found error. I don't know where the problem is. Please help.

This was my error,

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate in Page#home
```

> Showing /media/vic/pyrit/rails_dev/cartapp/cartapp/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #10 raised:
>
> Missing partial shared/_navigation with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
>     * "/media/vic/pyrit/rails_dev/cartapp/cartapp/app/views"
>     * "/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/devise-3.5.6/app/views"

Comment: Do you have `_havigation.html.erb` on `app/views/shared`?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Can you elaborate what your problem is and when it arises?

Comment: Yes.. I do have the navigation.html.erb on my shared folder under views

Answer (score 0):

I think your path is incorrect. Try this:

```
<%= render 'shared/navigation' %>
```

Comment: i did the same but the error maintains. My application.html.erb is so overcrowded with my navigation code and want to get rid of

Comment: Make sure that you have partial named as `_navigation.html.erb` in the folder `shared`.